# Django Login does not work after Deploy (pythonanywhere.com)

Tags: python, django, github, pythonanywhere, django-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my Django App for a few days. I got the Index Page Working after a lot of guessing.
Finally, I found the error. But now it is still not working correctly.

I've tried to follow this How To this time:
https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/de/django_installation/ and
https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/de/deploy/#registriere-dich-f%C3%BCr-ein-pythonanywhere-konto

So I Uploaded my Code to Github and made it Publicly available and I created a pythonanywhere project at this URL:
http://mvanthiel.pythonanywhere.com/catalog/ui/

I also created a virtual environment and created the .gitignore file.

On my Windows (Dev) Host the Website does work as expected.
On pythonanywhere.com it does not.

## Windows Dev

On Windows Dev, I pushed the Projekt content to git like explained in the how-to.

After that I tried two different ways:

## pythonanywhere.com

On pythonanywhere.com I installed the pip module.
`pip3.6 install --user pythonanywhere`
And then I tried to autoconfigure the rest on pythonanywhere.com with:
`pa_autoconfigure_django.py --python=3.6 https://github.com/HigeMynx/onboarding.git`
The Website is now Online available and I create a Django Superuser in the shell.

**But when I try to log in (on the website oder the admin panel) or register, I constantly get this Error Page:**
[image]

## SelfHosted Linux VM

I added a Service Account and removed and installed some packages.
After that, I cloned the Repository and created and activated the Virtual Environment.
Than i made shure that pip is installed and up to date, and installed some pip requirements.

```sh
sudo adduser onboarding
sudo usermod -aG sudo onboarding
su onboarding 
sudo apt purge *python2.7-minimal* -y && sudo apt purge *python2.7* -y && sudo apt purge python2.7-minimal python2.7 -y
sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -V -y && sudo apt-get autoremove -y && sudo apt-get install virtualenv python3 python3-pip python3-venv python3-virtualenv python3.6-venv -y
git clone https://github.com/HigeMynx/onboarding.git
python3 -m venv myvenv
source myvenv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

### Requirements.txt

```sh
autopep8~=1.4.4
coverage~=4.5.4
Django~=2.2.4
docutils~=0.14
et-xmlfile~=1.0.1
isort~=4.3.21
openpyxl~=2.6.0
virtualenv~=16.7.3
```

After that I created the superuser and migrated the database and so on:

```sh
sudo python3 manage.py shell
sudo python3 manage.py makemigrations -v3
sudo python3 manage.py migrate -v3
sudo isort -rc .
sudo python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput -v3
sudo python3 manage.py runserver 192.168.18.10:80 -v3
```

**But when I try to log in (on the website or the admin panel) or register, I constantly get no Error at all:**
All that happens is, that the Website relodes to the index page but besides this, it does absolutely nothing.

I can give you access to my pythonanywhere.com bash if needed, and you can look in my git code if needed.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Did you remember to include the `{% csrf_token %}` to that custom login page of yours?

Comment: Yes i did. But it does not change anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your PythonAnywhere page, I can replicate the CSRF error by going to http://mvanthiel.pythonanywhere.com/admin and using test/test as user/pass.

If I switch it to HTTPS, I get an authentication error instead of the CSRF error. Try using HTTPS instead of HTTP and see if that fixes your issue.

I believe this behavior is driven based on the CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE option in your settings file: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-secure

Comment: This *IS* Working, but only on pythonanywhere.com. If I try the same on the SelfHosted Linux VM the HTTPS://... The site won't load at all. So I have 2 Questions. First: Is there a way to tell Django to redirect to https automatically? Second and most important: How to enable HTTPS on SelfHosted Linux VM's'? I know I do have set CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  to True because in a later state this site should be live for customers and it should be at least half secure if you know what i mean.

Comment: @HigeMynx Those are very different questions than your original post and more complex than I can answer in a comment. Rerouting http to https is a networking question, enabling HTTPS with certs is a networking/security question, and there are resources available out there.

Comment: But even if I set CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  to false, it is not working. I have it now live on pythoneverywhere with CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  set to False. If you then try to Login with HTTP, you get the same "error" as on my self hosted Linux VM. It just reloads without doing anything basically.

Comment: @HigeMynx What have you done on your self hosted Linux machine to enable HTTPS? Do you have a HTTPS certificate? Which certificate authority are you using? Again, this is well outside the scope of your original question. I suggest you make a new post with your new question.

Comment: I'm trying the other way around at first. At this point, I've done nothing to enable HTTPS on my Linux Machine. I will use a Certificate from my work later on. I'll try it by myself and create a new Stack Post for this if I can't get it working. But for now, I'm trying to enable HTTP traffic/login. (Less Secure but I really just want ANY working Test-Page with Login and everything for now.)

Comment: Of Course only If this is Possible... Is this possible? Or would it be much easier to just try to get HTTPS up and running?

Comment: @HigeMynx Please make another post.

Comment: What for? Like I said for now I just want to get it working without SSL whatsoever. And this is not the case. I'm not able to login to my Django App. *ONLY* if I go to https://mvanthiel.pythonanywhere.com/catalog/ui/ it'll work but it works only because pythonanywhere.com has a Certificate already. Since I'm not able to Login, this Question is still not answered.

Comment: just a quick comment- on PythonAnywhere, under your web tab, you can set a config to force http -> https